# Prevent disabled dag from running past schedule when enabled

Tags: airflow

In Airflow 5.2.3, when a dag is enabled by pressing a button to change its state from off to on, the dag will run past schedule before the next scheduled run time .

Is it possible to set a dag to be enabled but not make its previous run until the next time its schedule to be run?

Tried using delete command to run day history and few other methods.

Answer (score 0):

you can set catchup to false to prevent this:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dag-run.html#catchup

```
with DAG(
    dag_id='some_dag',
     ..
    catchup=False,
```